# Reconnect after a PG::Error SSL SYSCALL error in Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I've recently experienced H12 request timeouts on Heroku caused by `PG::Error SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected`.

Relevant portions of the stack trace include:

```
2013-04-05T22:07:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/things/3.json host=things.herokuapp.com fwd="184.72.72.117" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0):
2013-04-05T22:07:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:294:in `dealloc'
2013-04-05T22:07:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:277:in `clear'
2013-04-05T22:07:58+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error (SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
2013-04-05T22:07:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:339:in `clear_cache!'
```

Heroku's documentation lists [common causes of this error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#pgerror-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected). Since I'm not using Resque or Unicorn, this seems to have been caused by a network partition.

The same documentation says, "When Heroku detects a crash, we kill that dyno and start a new one, which re-establishes the connection." This was not my experience. The application only recovered when I ran `heroku restart`. I would prefer to handle this error at the application level and not rely on Heroku's dyno management to save me.

Is there any way to catch an 'EOF detected' error and automatically retry until the application reconnects?

Comment: Is this on a dev/basic db or a production db?

Comment: @GregB - This is on a production Crane tier in an app with two web processes, i.e. `heroku ps:scale web=2`.

Comment: PostgreSQL auto-connect was merged into rails:3-2-stable [7 months ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7632).

I'm on 3.2.11, and it looks like this patch is in this version according to:

`git co v3.2.11`

`git log --grep=stevecj`

@steve-jorgensen - Is there something I need to do in the application to make this work?

Comment: This is very strange. Is there a rescue somewhere that is preventing a clean crash of the process? Would you please file a heroku support ticket so I dig into this a bit more?